# Running into errors while installing Yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install yarn on a new machine and after I enter `brew install yarn` this is what my command line spits out:

```
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-
apache/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-
core/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-
dupes/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-
php/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-
versions/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': 
Permission denied
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
==> Installing dependencies for yarn: icu4c, node
==> Installing yarn dependency: icu4c
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/icu4c-
60.1.high_sierra.bottle.t######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring icu4c-60.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/opt/icu4c
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced below issue while installing webpack in following configuration

Ubuntu 14.04

webpacker (3.0.2)

Rails 5.1.4

Ruby 2.3.1p112

I got below errors:

> Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 0.10.25 Please
>   upgrade Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/

I have fixed my issue following steps:

**Steps to install Vuejs via webpack in a rails app**

*The gem Webpacker solves lots of questions on how to integrate the frontend into the Rails app*

**Webpack prerequisites:** Ruby 2.2+, Rails 4.2+, Node.js 6.0.0+ and Yarn 0.25.2+

(**Note:-** Following steps for ubuntu 14.04 users)

**Step 1:** Install Nodejs

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install nodejs

**Step 2:** Install Yarn

- curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
- sudo apt-get install yarn

**Step 3:** Add webpack gem into your rails app

- gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.0'

then *bundle install*,

**Step 4:** Install Vue in rails app

- rails webpacker:install:vue

**Way to install vuejs packages**

For ex:

> npm install vue-strap

Now you installed vue-strap in your rails app,

Check your packages added or not in your rails app following step:

> cd /your_projec_name/node_modules

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the permissions inside the Homebrew directory have not set correctly.
You can either do something like this:

> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local

or

use npm to install yarn:

> brew uninstall yarn
>
> npm install yarn -g
>
> yarn global upgrade yarn